# High current flow in voltage regulation using TL494

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, constant-current, tl494, constant-voltage

I am using the given schematic for voltage regulation. When I’m not given the feedback, that is point A and B is not connected, then m getting a pulse of 35 % duty cycle of 0-12 V. But when  I’m connecting the feedback (A and B gets connected), then in the output I’m getting the 12 V DC rather than a pulse even though positive and negative terminal of error amplifier has some difference of voltage and there's a sudden large amount of current flow at point C and D. I am not understanding why pulse is getting vanished with 12 V DC and sudden increase in current in primary side of the transformer circuit. Is there any blunder in the schematic?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any connection between OpAmp output and driver looks independent of A-B point voltage according schematic above